# Localization events and messages in identityserver 3

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3

I am looking at options to localise events and error messages in. One option I found is IdentityServer3.Localization package. But I could not get details on how to bind this with Ids 3. Where should I keep the resource strings?

Answer (score 0):

There is a ILocalizationService that you can implement and register in the DI system. Here are the docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/localization.html. This is used for localizing all translatable strings.

If you want to localize the views, then that must be done via a custom view service: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customizingViews.html

Comment: is it possible to supply resource files as part of the host, like the way we can supply custom views in templates folder?

Comment: Updated the answer to add some info about views.

Comment: My implementation of ILocalizationService takes language locale. I need to inject instance of this service on each request.   var localizationService = new GlobalizedLocalizationService(new LocaleOptions { Locale = "cs-CZ" });
                options.Factory.LocalizationService = new Registration<ILocalizationService>(resolver => localizationService); Where do i need to do this? Doing this on startup will always inject the same language

Comment: You can register a delegate in the DI system in IdSvr. Inside this delegate you can resolve the current OWIN environment service, from which you can build an OwinContext to understand the current request so you can generate the correct localization service to return. We have an example of that somewhere in our samples -- prolly the DI one.

Comment: I was not successful in doing this as I could not find a good example. Trying my luck with other folks who are having the same problem here : https://github.com/johnkors/IdentityServer3.Contrib.Localization/issues/50

Comment: Here's a sample, @Shetty. 

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/LocalizedMessages/LocalizedMessages/Startup.cs#L45